# Plausibility of Impact Depth Approximation Assumptions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision

I was reading the Wikipedia article on Newton's approximation of [impact depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth), and the argument as presented made sense, but it seems to rely on the assumption that, upon collision of the object with the ground, the entirety of the object's momentum is transferred almost immediately to the earth (or whatever it is the object is impacting).

I'm not a physicist, but this seems like a rather strong and counterintuitive assumption to make.  My layman's assumption would be that, after the object of mass m with velocity v had displaced an equivalent amount of earth, I would effectively have a "combined" object of mass 2m with velocity v/2, then shortly thereafter an effective object of mass 3m with velocity v/3, etc.

I was, therefore, wondering to what extent the assumption above seems to hold, and why.  It also seems counterintuitive to me that, say, a (blunt, ideal) bullet fired at the ground at 500 m/s would penetrate to approximately the same depth as one fired at 5000 m/s or even 50000 m/s.  Granted, I don't *always* expect reality to conform to my expectations, particularly not at non-intuitive speeds, but my intuitive grasp of Newtonian mechanics is usually fairly sound.

Edit: In case my question is unclear, as the bot seems to think, my question is: (Under what circumstances) is Newton's approximation for impact depth a good approximation to reality; and if it is, why does the majority of the momentum transfer in this fashion, rather than as I proposed in my second paragraph?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.